# Disable Bluetooth but let user re-enable it?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, group-policy

Is is possible to disable Bluetooth by default (with a GPO), but give local users the rights to re-enable it? I'm talking about a scenario with domain joined Windows 10 laptops and users without admin rights.

Comment: Hello Volsk and welcome to Stack Exchange. What exactly is the reason behind this request? What do you hope to gain from such a setup?

Comment: Well, company policy is to disable bluetooth by default. And the claim is there is no way to give users the option to enable it by choice for those who do want Bluetooth.

Comment: If the default is to disable, but let users enable it if  they want, then the effective security gain is 0. Those who need it on a regular basis will be annoyed by having to enable it on every reboot, and those who don't need it won't bother anyways.

Comment: I fully agree. But now the situation is those who need/want it are completely out of luck. Also battery drain is an argument. Not mine.